# Firefox/Chrome addon socketio

Tags: firefox, socket.io, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to port chrome extension to firefox. My Chrome extension uses backgroung page to init one socketio connection on plugin start. Then in content page I send events to background page to emit events through socketio. So i have 1 connection and it is used by many tabs.

Is there any possibily to create something like this in FF? May be it's possible to create one shared worker for addon and communicate with worker from tabs? Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something a lot like a background-page in Firefox using the SDK's [PageWorker api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker). Here's a *really* simple example:

*index.js*

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var page = require("sdk/page-worker");
var re = new RegExp("^https://www.google.*");

let { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

let button = ActionButton({
  id: "my-button-id",
  label: "Button Label",
  icon: {
    "16": "chrome://mozapps/skin/extensions/extensionGeneric.png",
    "32": "chrome://mozapps/skin/extensions/extensionGeneric.png"
  },
  onClick: function(state) {
    main();
  }
});

var worker;

function main() {

  let contentURL = 'https://www.google.ca/';
  if (worker) {
    worker.contentURL = contentURL;
  }

  worker = page.Page({
    include: re,
    contentURL: contentURL,
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScriptFile: data.url('worker.js')
  });

  worker.port.on('fromWorker', (m) => {
    console.log("got message", m);
    worker.port.emit('toWorker', true)
  });
}
```

*worker.js*

```
console.log("worker> attached...");
self.port.on('toWorker', function(message) {
  console.log("worker>", message);
});
self.port.emit("fromWorker", "message from content worker: "+ [document.location, document.title].join(', '));
```

If you want to interact with scripts loaded into the page, you'll need to proxy through the content script into the page via postMessage, [see these docs for more help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts).

Comment: I have already found this solution, but thanks for the answer